# How To Prevent Overriding in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

In C# if we inherit from a class, it allows us to override the virtual methods.

This can be prevented by not using the `virtual` keyword with a method but still it can be hidden by implementing the method with the `new` keyword.

Is there anyway to prevent overriding and shadowing without making it the method private?

```
class myBaseClass{
    public void method1(){ //Implementation }
}

class myDerivedClass : myBaseClass{
    public new void method1() { //new Implementation }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can always be hidden, but that's not overriding - it's shadowing. It's important to understand the difference between the two. You can't prevent shadowing though (while permitting the class itself to be derived from), no. Why do you want to? What ill effect are you trying to prevent?

Sealing the class itself is a separate option though:

```
sealed class MyBaseClass {
    ...
}
```

Personally I like to seal any class which I don't *design* to be derived from, but that's a different (and controversial) matter.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: This *isn't* overriding, as I stated. It's shadowing, and you can't prevent it. The shadowing method won't be called polymorphically though.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: If you understand that it's not shadowing, please stop calling it overriding... and you haven't stated that you *have* to completely prevent shadowing - you've said you *want* to. If you *have* to, you should just give up right now, or pick a different language.

Answer (score 3):

From reading your question and your comments it would seem that the actual solution might not be in code but in understanding.

When you override a method (which *has* to be a virtual method before you can override it) that method is call for any object of that type regardsless of the compile time type

For an explanation of the difference in overriding and hiding see the code below

```
public class BaseClass {

   public virtual void MyVirtual(){ 
      Console.writeLine("Base virtual");
   }

   public void MyNonVirtual(){
      Console.WriteLine("Base non virtual");
   }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass {

   public virtual void MyVirtual(){ 
      Console.writeLine("Derived virtual");
   }

   public new void MyNonVirtual(){
      Console.WriteLine("Derived non virtual");
   }
}

BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
Derived d = new Derived();
BaseClass dAsb = d;

b.MyVirtual(); //prints Base virtual
b.MyNonVirtual(); //print Base non virtual

d.MyVirtual(); //prints Derived virtual
d.MyNonVirtual(); //print Derived non virtual

dAsb.MyVirtual(); //prints Derived virtual
dAsb.MyNonVirtual(); //print Base non virtual
```

Notice that the last line will ***not*** use the method defined in Derived but the method from the base class because it's not virtual the *compile* time type determines which method will be called and the *compile* time type of `dAsb` is BaseClass. So even though `d` and `dAsb` are exactly the same object two different methods will be called because the compile time types are different.
Any code written with the BaseClass in mind will work as expected regardless of someone hiding the non virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the method `sealed`:

```
public sealed void method1()
{
    //Implementation 
}
```

Of course, you can't completely stop it. I might have misunderstood your question however, as it seems you might be wanting to prevent shadowing, as Jon Skeet put. There's no way to stop that.

Comment: That's the method, not the class - and a non-overriding method is sealed by default. That's why the OP has to use `new` in the derived class.

Comment: Sealed class can not be inherited but I have to allow the inheritance for class and you can not sealed a method until it is override from base class: `sealed override void method1(){ //Implementation }`